# Return values from an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm very new to JS and Node. My confusion is how do I push the values from an async task to a array and then print the array once all the operations are done.

My code is:

```
function movieNames(dirname) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        dir.files(dirname, function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(files)
            }
        })
    })
}


function movieMetadata(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        probe(path, function (err, probeData) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(probeData)
            }
        })
    })
}

var movies = []
movieNames('D:/Media').then(function (moviepaths) {
    moviepaths.forEach(function (moviepath) {
        movieMetadata(moviepath).then(function (movie) {
         //console.log(movie)
        movies.push(movie)
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
    })
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error)
}).then(function () {
    console.log(movies)
})
```

When I run this code, it just prints the empty array '[]'.

Also I run the following code:

```
var i=0;
movieNames('D:/Media').then(function (moviepaths) {
    moviepaths.forEach(function (moviepath) {
        movieMetadata(moviepath).then(function (movie) {
         //console.log(movie)
        movies.push(movie)
        console.log(i++)
        // movies = movie
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
    })
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error)
}).then(function () {
    console.log(movies)
})
```

Output is: node movieNames.js
[]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18

I cannot understand why console.log(movies) is getting executed before the console.log(i++). If i just get this fixed, the code should run fine i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions need to return the data also right now they are returning only promise

```
  function movieNames(dirname) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        dir.files(dirname, function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
              return  reject(err)
            } else {
               return resolve(files)
            }
        })
    })
}


function movieMetadata(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        probe(path, function (err, probeData) {
            if (err) {
               return reject(err)
            } else {
               return resolve(probeData)
            }
        })
    })
}

var movies = []
movieNames("D:/Media").then(function(moviepaths){
    moviepaths.forEach(function(moviepath){
        movieMetadata(moviepath).then(function(movie){
            movies.push(movie)
        },function(err){
            console.log(error)
        })
    })
    console.log(movies)
     return movies;
},function(err){
    console.log(err)
}).then(function(movies){
   console.log(movies);
})
```

Comment: Ran the above code and still console.log(movies) print an empty array '[]'.

Comment: could you log movie in movieMetadata?

Comment: your function chaining is incorrect. i'm updating my answer.

Comment: I made a console.log() within forEach function. I notice that console.log(movies) is getting printed before the forEach finishes.

I need to synchronize it but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I see that you have removes the console.log(movies). But my goal is to print the movies array at the end.

Comment: do you really want to make async call in foreach loop? that you can do after forEach loop is done.

Comment: moviepaths is an array of filenames and the function movieMetadata takes one filename and gets its metadata. So i believe i do need to call that function within the foreach loop.

Comment: How ever using .then twice on the same method is incorrect. i updated my answer again as you want to print the list. 
 movieMetadata(moviepath).then(function(movie){
console.log(movie)//can you see if it's logging?

Comment: Still prints an empty array. 

However if I replace movies.push(movie) with console.log(movie), then it logs movie individually.

Comment: as your movieNames is returning an promise so try to return the list in the end and see if that work.

Answer (score -1):

try this example: http://jsbin.com/hipisogilu/edit?js,console
You need to nest your promises chain, because it is asynchronous

Comment: Did the same exact thing, but still  get an empty array. I think the problem is I'm calling the async function probe within foreach. but i don't see another way to do it.